# PHP MySQL Order By with Where clause

Tags: php, mysql

I need to ORDER BY `number` field in ASC order but it is not working.

```
$sThree = "SELECT `id`, `name`, `number`, `logo` FROM `itv` WHERE `id` = {$rTwoArray['service_id']} ORDER BY `number` ASC";
$qThree = mysql_query($sThree, $conn1);
$rThree[] = mysql_fetch_assoc($qThree);
```

[image]

Couldn't figure out, please help me debug.

Comment: what is data type of `number` field in mysql ?

Comment: @Viral `number` field is int(11)

Comment: Did you try to run query manually?

Comment: you are checking for id=some_value in query. so the array you posted should have same id. but it have different id. I think you creating an array through php loop with select query in it

Comment: The query shown above is different and the result image is different.
You have used `WHERE id = {something}` it should give all same `id` in the result. Please attach correct result.

Comment: Its possible that the query result you are getting here is coming from another query that is why you are unable to get the ordered result.

Comment: Thanks!! Found that the queries are in `foreach` loop. I need to explicitly sort the array.

Comment: I have posted the same as answer. You can choose it if it helped you. Thanks.

Comment: Be aware that the old mysql_* extension which you're using is deprecated in version 5.5 of PHP (the current version) and is being removed from version 7 (the next version). You need migrate over to using either the mysqli_* extension or PDO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query shown above is different and the result image is different. You have used `WHERE id = {something}` it should give all same `id` in the result. Please attach correct result.

Its possible that the query result you are getting here is coming from another query that is why you are unable to get the ordered result.

Whenever code behaves unnaturally, firstly see if the code is working in a loop or what and never assume.

Answer (score 0):

use MySQL `CAST(expression AS TYPE)`

```
order by CAST(number AS SIGNED) ASC
```

Try this MySQL query

```
$sThree = "SELECT `id`, `name`, `number`, `logo` FROM `itv` 
WHERE `id` = {$rTwoArray['service_id']} order by CAST(number AS SIGNED) ASC";
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the queries were in a loop, I sorted the final array.

```
    $sThree = "SELECT `id`, `name`, `number`, `logo` FROM `itv` WHERE `id` = {$rTwoArray['service_id']}";
    $qThree = mysql_query($sThree, $conn1);
    $rThree[] = mysql_fetch_assoc($qThree);

usort($rThree, function ($item1, $item2) {
    return $item1['number'] >= $item2['number'];
});
debug($rThree);
```